# no matching function to call

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

1.getting an error while using copy constructor with overloaded operator +
 2.when copy constructor was removed from the code it worked fine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;
class number {
  int n,p;
  public:
  number () {
     n= random ();
    p = random()+random();
    cout << "constructor with random called"<< endl;
}
number (int n1, int p1) {
    n =n1;
    p=p1;
    cout << "Constructor with value called"<< endl;
    cout << "n ="<< n<< endl;
    cout << "p = " << p<< endl;
}
int random () {
    srand (time(0));
int tmp =rand()%100;
return (tmp);
}
number operator +(number &obj1) ;
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out,number &obj) ;
number (number &obj) {
     n= obj.n; 
      p=obj.p;
  }
} ;
 number number::operator+(number &obj1) {
    int tmp1 = n+obj1.n ;
     int tmp2 = p+obj1.p;
     return number (tmp1,tmp2);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   number n1;
number n2;
cout<< n1<< endl;
cout<< n1<< endl;
//cout << n1+n2<< endl;
return 0;
}
```

1)getting an error while using copy constructor with overloaded operator +
2)when copy constructor was removed from the code it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

Your copy constructor takes lvalue, while constructor generated by default takes rvalue.

Change your constructor with:

```
number (const number &obj)
//      ^^^^^
```

But I see no reason for user-defined copy constructor here.